# how to compile a modified videoInput.h

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to use the modified videoInput library which has the func 
`deviceSetupWithSubtype()`
(It's not the original videoInput library)

I got the `.h` and `.cpp` in the `rar` at the end of this page:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/CameraCapture

I tried to compile it with VC2010 Express C++, and I got my .lib, but when I put it in the program in which I want to use the modified videoInput.h, I get a lot of LNK errors such as:

```
videoInput.lib(videoInput.obj) :error LNK2001:  unresolved external symbol __imp__CoTaskMemFree@4 

videoInput.lib(videoInput.obj) :error LNK2001:  unresolved external symbol _MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB24 

videoInput.lib(videoInput.obj) :error LNK2001:  unresolved external symbol _MEDIASUBTYPE_AYUV 

videoInput.lib(videoInput.obj) :error LNK2001:  unresolved external symbol _MEDIASUBTYPE_Y211
```

(I tried also the normal videoInput.lib and it works well, but it's not the version I need).

How can I solve that?
Or if you just have this modified videoInput.lib, could you upload it?
Thank you.

EDIT:

In release mode, I get also this error:

```
videoInput.lib(videoInput.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for  '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2'
```

Comment: You have an unresolved external symbol, which means you aren't linking with something you should link with. Try to build it with the makefile that comes with the source.

Comment: I have no experience with makefile, anyway I searched something, so I did from the console: nmake -f Makefile.win, but I got this error: makefile.win(24) : fatal error U1001: syntax error : illegal character '{' in macroStop.

Comment: In a folder there are these files: makefile.win videoInputLib.a videoInputLib.dev and videoInputLib.layout          In another folder there are the videoInput.cpp videoInput.h and videoInput.o

Comment: I see that the makefile was created in dev-c++ using mingw. So it doesn't invoke cl.exe anyway. Regardless, this not the place the to teach about makefiles, nor is it relevant to you. Take a look at the folder "Modified videoinputlib\DevCpp-CompileAsLib" in the archive. There are instructions there to build in `dev-c++`, I'm afarid there's isn't anything else I can offer.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching on the link errors I tried with many libs, at the end I found the solution:
you must add these lines in videoInput.h (eventually adjust the paths in the linker, I didn't need it):

```
// if gives error LNK2038: mismatch detected for   '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2'
// insert _ALLOW_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL_MISMATCH in the C++ preprocessor option in the project properties
// these are the library needed:
#pragma comment (lib, "oleaut32")
#pragma comment (lib, "ole32")
#pragma comment (lib, "user32")
#pragma comment (lib, "strmbase")
```

Now the resulting videoInput.lib compiles correctly.